Why is The Milgram Experiment used in reference to the Nazis free will
This may be more of a psychology question but having  received no answer on the psychology forum  I'm asking it here  in relation to free will. The Milgram experiment https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment is frequently cited as proof that most people in the Nazis situation would act similar to them. I don’t understand that conclusion because Milgram's experiment was completely unlike the Nazi's actual experience and situation.
Milgram's experiment may prove that most people would obey a direct order from an authority figure against their own will and better judgment, if the order was given in a one on one setting. Particularly when the the authority figure is standing right there and acting coercive like Milgram's people were. That is all.
But that is not the situation the Nazis were facing. Unlike the subjects of Milgram's experiment the Nazis:
(1) Weren’t being micromanaged. They did not have an authority figure standing directly over them  telling them what to do at every move and turn.
(2) Had time to think over what they were doing and opportunity to discuss it with others.
(3) Were given more of an option to stop if they requested it. Unlike Milgram's subject they weren’t told on their fourth request to stop “You have no other choice; you must go on” which borders on an open threat (in general if you are looking to study and compare to the Nazi's where did refusal of the first four requests to stop come from? Is there any evidence whatsoever that the Nazis had a similar across the board policy of saying no to the first four transfer requests?)
(4)Did not show the signs of distress Milgram's subjects did
(5)In many cases acted with cruelty exceeding  what their original orders had been. e.g. They may have been  told to murder  babies. No one told them to do so in some of the gruesome ways  they were witnessed actually doing so
(6)Were not receiving orders on a one on one basis. Studies have shown that even in situations where most people would give in to an external pressure they would not do so if they can find even one ally in resisting that pressure.
It seems to me that for the Milgram experiment to be analogous to the Nazis experience you would need to conduct the experiment with (a) a large group of subjects being given orders at once and (b) after giving orders the authority figure recedes to the background (c)is allowing the subjects a certain degree of flexibility and permission to make judgment calls.
Why is Milgram so frequently cited in relation to the Nazis in any context?

Did you miss the part of the Holocaust where military forces went around literally murdering millions of people? You don't think there's much pressure to conform or suppress distress there? Or are you strictly considering the time before they started murdering millions of people? But before they started murdering people, they weren't murdering people, so it wouldn't really make sense to compare it to that part, given that the experiment is related to the murdering. If you want some actual decent arguments questioning the applicability to the Holocaust, there are some on the Wikipedia page.

Because that was Milgram's own interpretation, which was subsequently much criticized for its "use in connection". And even critics admitted that the pattern  discovered by Milgram may account for some aspects of Nazi behavior, such as "dutiful destructiveness of the dispassionate bureaucrat who may have shipped Jews to Auschwitz with the same degree of routinization as potatoes to Bremerhaven". Some find this insidious banality of evil, as Hanna Arendt called it, even more terrifying than outright monstrosities.

The issue has been discussed by historians Ch.Browning, Ordinary men: Reserve Police Battalion 101 and the Final Solution in Poland (1992) and Daniel Goldhagen, Hitler's Willing Executioners: Ordinary Germans and the Holocaust (1996): in fact, Nazis performed "real life" experiments.

If you believe the Nazis were a uniquely evil group then their behavior is not a real life experiment. It's just the way evil people act when given a chance. Were most countries to give instructions and free reign to kill it's perceived enemies they would have those who go along with it. The question is if those who were NOT predisposed to doing so would go along with it too because they were told to

@NotThatGuy An interesting live demo.  (How authentic I won't vouch). To assume that if we were in 1930s Germany we would have been anything other than obedient Nazis is to presume near superhuman integrity

"Ask not for whom the bell tolls, the bell tolls for thee."

@Schmerel Who says Nazis are the unique evil? Evil is ok. But unique (or supreme) is an impossible claim to justify. Eg.  WWII killed 1% of the entire earth's population. Chenghiz Khan killed 10% with the "help" of only horses and swords not 20th century technology like industrial gas chambers. The only time there is recorded man made cooling of the planet

Swiss psychologist Alice Miller argues that Nazi's were formerly abused children who could easily identify with aggressive authority figures who rationalize sadism. She argues that ideology driven sadism is always rooted unconsciously in abusive child rearing. In my judgment people who are abused in childhood sacrifice their emotional development; they attempt to "grow up faster"; and they live with unconscious abandonment trauma. The best ego defense is to make efforts to conform to social norms. Addicts and deviants defy norms but risk aggression from folks who demand compliance with norms.

@SystemTheory Jesus... Abuse victims deserve more compassion and kindness than to have a "potential Nazi" trivially label slapped on them - one would need a ton of evidence to justify making that claim. Also, there were millions of Nazis, so it seems like you'd have a really hard time having the numbers add up such that they were all formerly abused (and I can't find Miller making that claim, although I didn't look too hard, and she did make a questionable similar claim about Hitler). At best one can recognise that abuse may be one of many factors that influences behaviour in complex ways.

@NotThatGuy - Alice Miller makes forceful arguments for the consequences of child abuse in all of her books. See this article for example: https://www.pacesconnection.com/blog/alice-miller-s-for-your-own-good-hidden-cruelty-in-child-rearing-and-the-roots-of-violence Miller claimed that most cases of addiction, neuroses, chronic depression, and a slew of other disorders were caused by buried feelings and unresolved trauma and grief related to some form of child abuse. She wrote extensively on why she believed that these problems impacted not just the individual, but society as a whole.

@NotThatGuy - See link in the comment above: To make her case, Miller uses the example of Hitler’s childhood to show the genesis of his insatiable hatred, which, of course, resulted in the horrifying fate of the Jews in the Third Reich. Specifically, Miller describes how the parenting manuals that were in vogue when Hitler and his Nazi collaborators were children belied extreme hostility to children. Parents were exhorted to “show no mercy” when it came to breaking the child’s will. Rather, parents were advised to withhold affection and enforce rigid obedience by whatever means necessary.

[Edited]

The Milgram experiment is frequently cited as proof that most people in the Nazis situation would act similar to them.

Many research is misquoted or used of proof for which it isn't. There is nothing very interesting about some media exaggerating claims to get more attention. It's what media does.
The Milgram experiment demonstrates that an attitude of following authority over personal moral values is possible with average people of various cultures, not a special German trait. That's all it proves.
According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milgram_experiment):

Milgram suspected before the experiment that the obedience exhibited by Nazis reflected of a distinct German character, and planned to use the American participants as a control group before using German participants, expected to behave closer to the Nazis. However, the unexpected results stopped him from conducting the same experiment on German participants.

Intuitively many people would think or say: "If I saw this kind of thing happening or were asked to participate, of course I would object! But those Germans are different."
The experiment reveals that in a specific lab setting where people would think the same, they actually follow authority.
By showing that the intuition is wrong for the lab setting, it is much more easily to also imagine that in a real world setting, our intuition about how average people would behave is wrong. This is not direct proof that most people would not act different, but it is evidence making this more likely, in particular given there are also no other known general behavioral differences between Germans and citizens of neighboring countries.
According to the same Wikipedia page, Milgram also said (years later):

The legal and philosophic aspects of obedience are of enormous importance, but they say very little about how most people behave in concrete situations.


Why is Milgram so frequently cited in relation to the Nazis in any context?

It is what is called a "landmark experiment" for this kind of research, and it reveals that any intuition like "Those things were done by nasty Germans, but me and my peers are so much better so I would act differently, this kind of thing could not happen here" should not be said so lightly.
Because it is one of the earliest experiments of that kind, it got a lot of attention, was cited a lot and is thus well-known. The experiment was repeated in same and in many other ways, also different experiments were conducted, all deepening our understanding. In the relevant sciences, the sum of all experiments may be more relevant, or maybe some other variant, but to the outside, the name of this experiment is more useful as people will more easily recognize the name.

This distinction between perpetrators, party members, opportunists, hanger-ons, bystanders and dissidents is a lot more complicated than the ideas of joined before or after a certain date, makes it sound like. A lot more than the party was needed to keep the system of destruction running and even people who might have been coerced did it voluntarily while you'd have a hard time assessing the personally felt damocles sword of the system. And I'd not be so sure that the conviction of the perpetrators is so crystal clear either, but I'm not a psychologist.

I am only referring to the OP ambiguous usage of "The Nazis" in my explanation of the different categories. I weakened the early vs. late description. Perpetrators where many, I did not draw any line between perpetrators and non-perpetrators, just between what is called Nazis and non-Nazis. Non-Nazis were also perpetrators in many cases, and those are more relevant to the Milgram experiment.


Why is Milgram so frequently cited in relation to the Nazis in any context?

As conifold commented: Because Milgram himself set them in this context:

Obedience, as a determinant of behavior, is of
particular relevance to our time. It has been reliably established that from 1933–45 millions of innocent persons were systematically slaughtered on
command.

[...]

These inhumane policies may have
originated in the mind of a single person, but they
could only be carried out on a massive scale if a very large number of persons obeyed orders.

Also for historical context. The Nazi party (founded 1919) was under Hitler's control since 1921, they were the German government since 1933 and started annexations since 1938 with continuous warfare since 1939. The murdering of Jews and other real or supposed adversaries was a continuous process but the final solution (industrial genocide) started 1941. By 1945 the war has ended with a brief period of "denazification" that only really the U.S. seems to have taken serious and only for a very short period of time before a) it revealed itself to be a bigger task than anticipated and b) before the cold war made the U.S. lose interest in denazification. By 1949 the federal republic of Germany (West Germany) and the democratic republic of Germany (East Germany) were founded and by 1955 West Germany joined NATO and had nukes stationed on it's territory.
And apparently Milgram started his initial experiments in 1961 only months after the trial of Adolf Eichmann has commenced, one of the key organizers and tasked with the logistics of the industrial genocide, who didn't appear to be a fanatic sociopath, but presented himself as dutiful servant, law abiding citizen and more motivated by professionalism and career than by antisemitism. Which lead Hanna Arendt to the analysis of the "banality of evil".
So lots of people speculated over how a society could go from normal to genocide to normal (even allies), how ordinary people could be turned into killers (as that must have happened with that scale and scope), how believable these defenses of "just following orders" actually were and whether that is a particular German thing or whether that could happen to anyone.
Now if we set aside a racism arguing of "it's in their genes", there are still quite some arguments for why the German situation was kinda unique or how it could have been a perfect storm of bad circumstances. For example antisemitism was already widespread and had a long history and tradition (not exclusively in Germany, but that makes it only worse), the rise of the Nazis followed the aftermath of the first industrial war and one that was lost, so starvation, desperation, trauma, violence (active and passive) were pretty fresh in memory and violence as a political mean was somewhat normalized and accepted. It was the first attempt at a democratic republic so rather than being able to built on a broad consensus and only few outliers, the "fringes" (though not necessarily a unified block) became increasingly larger with lots of crisis (until they formed a majority but due to their opposition made it impossible to form a majority government). By 1925 an outspoken anti-democrat became president and from 1930 onwards the government was put in place by the president and often ruled by emergency legislation rather than parliamentary majority. So with the conservatives being monarchists, the social democrats (the backbone of the democratic republic) already having to resort to emergency legislation, use of the military to gun down political violence and a general distrust for either that particular or democratic republics in general growing among the population, Hitler's claim for a dictatorship might have been less of an outlier than it should have been.
The other thing is that the Nazi party particularly gained traction after democracy was already in decline when non-nazi fascists of the old regime had already sabotaged the system and enforced a gridlock where they ruled parallel to the institutions or with tolerance of them rather than with majorities. So when the centrist parties got so sabotaged and locked that things didn't work, the extremist positions got traction. Where Hitler somewhat tuned down the antisemitism and presented himself as an all-German savior in a system that is completely fractured.
And the other thing that fascists profit from was that the socialists often worked against the system, while the fascists presented themselves as working for the system but on steroids. So the conservative establishment was more likely to accept extremists preaching to the choir, more willing to look the other way if the people they attacked are the political enemy and also more willing to cooperate with them and thus to normalize the insane. But while for conservatives scapegoat populism was a means to an end, for the Nazi party it was an end in itself. And the more the conservatives failed with realpolitics, the more the Nazis could profit from ideological integrity.
Also they might have been philosophically and scientifically in a unique position where "scientific racism", "eugenics", "antisemitic conspiracy theories", "revolutionary terror" and "applied dialectics" were much more accepted ideas. Like while often already challenged or actually debunked, they could cite plenty of Americans on racism and one drop rules, could cite credible scientiest (at the time) on eugenics, could reprint the Protocols of the Elders of Zion as evidence (despite being proven to be a forgery even back then but apparently not widely known), they could look at Marxist or Leninist literature copy sections on dialetics of class antagonism and class warfare and rebrand them as race war antagonism and race warfare. By casting antagonists as race they could profited from long established principles of exploiting and throwing minorities under the bus without the majority asking questions and feeling scared for themselves, because "they are just inherently different".
So while these themes sound wacky from today's point of view and probably from the point of view of many groups back then, these ideas were probably still more present in the public discourse than they are now or at least might have sounded similar to what's in the public discourse. So the baseline level of people who would have genuinely believed that nonsense could have already been pretty high. I mean in free and fair elections the Nazi party scored 33-37% in unfair elections 42% (before they scored ~100% because they were the only option). So while not a majority (and certainly some protest voters dissatisfied with the status quo and not deterred by the rhetoric and program) that is already a lot. Add to that the non-nazi fascists who were already in favor of dictatorships and authoritarianism and wouldn't mind the antisemitism or the persecution of leftists and you already have a majority. Despite the amount of committed ideologues probably being much smaller. Though that also means a lot of ordinary people must have participated that were not convinced by the narrative, saw the evil and still took part.
So the narrative was that this was a uniquely German problem and that others would have resisted if given such orders. And now look at the Milgram experiment. The predictive estimate among peers was 1.2% would fail the experiment  and go all the way, the actual score was 65%. With no excuses of trauma, background, hatred, bias, politics, etc, just because they were told to or you know the whopping $4/h ($41 in today's money)...
And they went through torture all the way up to murder and desecration of a corpse just because of being told and reassured that it's fine.
That outcome was rather unexpected, by Milgram and his peers apparently, I even read somewhere that this experiment was just meant as a baseline test and that he had intended to run the experiment with Germans later on and compare it to the American result though with these results on the American test he could have hardly justified his initial claim of that being a German feature.
So this experiments adds to the discussion that obedience is quite a strong force potentially able to override discomfort and realization of moral wrongs.
But whether that is able to actually explain the Nazi crimes is questionable. For example Milgram's experiment looks at the action of the individual, but especially within the context of the Nazi ideology, group mentalities, peer pressure, conformity and the "creation of an alternate reality" maybe be also of interest.
Like sure if you conceptualize Hitler as being the sole culprit of the ideology, maybe an inner circle, but the rest just being followers then it's impossible for them to be everywhere at once to supervise everything. However if you realize that they ran a totalitarian regime, applied a "Gleichschaltung" of all organizations, then this idea of "going home from Nazi duty and contemplating your deeds and meeting with your non-nazi friends" doesn't really work anymore. You're never outside of the system, you've got banners everywhere reminding you of the parties reach and if you do crimes and perceive people doing crimes, then you don't need Hitler standing behind you, YOU become the supervisors to each other. Like if you watched dissidents being deported, traitors being shot and people joyfully killing people, would you go to them and talk about your moral qualms? And if you don't and shoot people in a way that appears to be without qualms would you expect people with their moral qualms to approach you? So who would you talk to?
And if it's "normal", if "everyone does it", if you're by far "not the worst offender", how bad could it actually be? Like similar to the Milgram experiment you could see that as an "alternate reality" as some sort of "game scenario". Like the government wouldn't actually let Milgram run an experiment where I torture and kill people, right? If I had to kill them they must have done something wrong, right? That can't be what it looks like otherwise someone would have stopped me, would have stopped all the others by now, right? RIGHT!???
So to some extend you don't need to create sociopaths, it's sufficient to not stop them and to normalize their behavior and to make it weird not to follow that role model to create an "alternate reality".
Some of these questions could already have been relevant in Milgram's experiment, but they are much more pressing in totalitarian systems. Like in (3) you pretend as if the 4 prods are a high bar. But in reality, these people believed to live in a free country, with constitutional rights, a rule of law and all that stuff. Where what they've just witnessed is or at least should be illegal. No matter how many prods you'd have compiled for them, they could have stood up and told you to stick your $4 where the sun never shines and leave. And if you threatened coerced or otherwise tried to appeal to them, they would be within their rights to use all means available to them including violence to break free and they would know that the legal system would have their backs on that.
While in a totalitarian system, even if you are technically allowed to refuse orders you might nonetheless be hazed by your "peers", so these offers of opting out aren't always genuine. Imagine a full metal jacket scenario. Where the supervisor doesn't have to cruelly penalize by himself, but just sets a baseline level of "moral" behavior and punishes all singling out one as culprit. What you end up with is a self-oppressive system where people try to outperform each other just to not be the one that is being abused (by the rest). And if they've all built up guilt, they're in too deep to complain.
And in a military context where you can pretend that relying on each other means "life or death" and where you can pretend that hazing isn't just torture to enforce obedience but can pretend it serves a purpose that narrative might work longer before people are in too deep and the Nazi attempted a militarized society.

(4)Did not show the signs of distress Milgram's subjects did

Milgram did a momentary analysis after the shock and revealed everything is fine. While actual war criminals probably come to realize that things aren't fine and in consequence either feel distressed or rationalize that before themselves to avoid that realization. So while not a psychologist I'd assume that is a different process and yeah not applicable.

(6)Were not receiving orders on a one on one basis. Studies have shown that even in situations where most people would give in to an external pressure they would not do so if they can find even one ally in resisting that pressure.

Yes the specific character of the experimenter could also figure in to how well the participants respond.

It seems to me that for the Milgram experiment to be analogous to the Nazis experience you would need to conduct the experiment with (a) a large group of subjects being given orders at once and (b) after giving orders the authority figure recedes to the background (c)is allowing the subjects a certain degree of flexibility and permission to make judgment calls.

As far as I know even Milgram's example sparked outrage about ethical considerations when conducting experiments (like you actually make people torture and kill people before they realize they didn't, what trauma that may or may not cause in the participants was often overlooked but is very relevant) and group based experiments like that "the third wave" had apparently also been conducted. Not an expert to tell you how scientifically useful they actually are, like there are many different interpretation of Milgram's experiments on top of criticism of the validity and methodology and whatnot. The reason why they are probably still talked about has likely more to do with their prevalence in pop culture and the shocking realization that things might not be as far away in space and time as people like them to be.
